# SQLite FireDAC trailing spaces

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

I'm using Delphi XE7 with FireDAC to access SQLite.

When I put data into a TEXT field, any trailing spaces or #0 characters get truncated.

Is there something I can change in either SQLite or FireDAC to have it preserve the trailing white space?

```
// The trailing spaces after Command don't come back from SQLite.
fFireDACQuery.ParamByName(kSQLFieldScriptCommands).AsString := 'Command          ';
```

Comment: Set the [`FormatOptions.StrsTrim`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDFormatOptions.StrsTrim) property to False.

Comment: P.S. don't be confused from the initial description of the `StrsTrim` property. There is a note saying *"For SQLite, this property is applied to all string columns, including ftMemo, ftWideMemo, ftString, ftWideString, ftFixedChar, and ftFixedWideChar."* which is just your case.

Comment: Sounds like a good answer, then why post it as a comment, not under "Your Answer" below?

Comment: I've set FormatOptions.StrsTrim to False and it fixed some of the cases but not all of them. The ones missed are those with #0 at the end of the string (as a character). I'm using ShortStrings because C-style strings have their own problems with an actual #0 inside the string.

Answer (score 2):

Disable the [**StrsTrim**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDFormatOptions.StrsTrim) property. This property is described as:

> **TFDFormatOptions.StrsTrim**
>
> Controls the removing of trailing spaces from string values and zero
>   bytes from binary values.

And it seems that you want to store binary data rather than text. If that is correct, better define your field data type e.g. as [**BINARY[255]**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC#Mapping_SQLite_to_FireDAC_Data_Types) for fixed length binary string of 255 bytes (255 is the maximum length of [**ShortString**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ShortString) that you use).

Parameter value for such field you would then access this way:

```
var
  Data: RawByteString;
begin
  ReadByteDataSomehow(Data);

  FDQuery.FormatOptions.StrsTrim := False;
  FDQuery.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO MyTable (MyBinaryField) VALUES (:MyBinaryData)';
  FDQuery.ParamByName('MyBinaryData').AsByteStr := Data;
  FDQuery.ExecSQL;
end;
```